# Linking custom taxonomies and posts

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, custom-taxonomy, advanced-taxonomy-queries

Im trying to figure out how to display data from custom post's into a custom taxonomy in a different post type.

I currently have 2 sections. **Work** & **Talent**. **Work** will display individual work/pieces and **Talent** will display individual artists. They both sit on the left hand side, in the admin area, like pages and posts do.

What I would like to happen is once I have created an artist(post) that sits under **Talent** this data is pulled through to **Work**. So within **Work** it would show a custom taxonomy listing out all of the artists names which I can then assign to the piece of work. Then on the front end side of this pull through the artists name and further data from the **Talent** section but is display on a **Work** page.

I don't want to have to manually re-enter each artist's information to a **Work** post as if the artist updates their information I have to manually go in to each **Work** post and update it.

Any advice on this would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this using the plugin "Advanced Custom Fields", just create a field type "post object" and them associate this field with the "Work" custom post.

Later in your template, you can get the artist data, a object with all elements by your custom post named Talent.

Advanced Custom Fields have a great documentation and is free, you can download it from http://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/

Comment: Please provide a link to the plugin and also state your affiliation